# Calculate the determinant of the matrix

Tags: determinant

I'm asked to find the determinant of a matrix $B$ if:

$$A=\left |\begin{bmatrix}
        a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
        b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
        c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right|=-k$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
        a_3 & a_2 & a_1 \\
        b_3-2a_3 & b_2-2a_2 & b_1-2a_1 \\
        c_3 & c_2 & c_1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

I used rule of Sarrus in order to find the determinant and finally I got:

For $A$:
$$-k=a_1b_2c_3+a_2b_3c_1+a_3b_1c_2-a_3b_2c_1-a_1b_3c_2-a_2b_1c_3$$
$$k=-a_1b_2c_3-a_2b_3c_1-a_3b_1c_2+a_3b_2c_1+a_1b_3c_2+a_2b_1c_3$$

I also factorised to get this:
$$k=b_2(a_3c_1-a_1c_3)+b_1(a_2c_3-a_3c_2)+b_3(a_1c_2-a_2c_1) \tag{1}$$

For $B$:

$$(b_2-2a_2)(a_3c_1-a_1c_3)+(b_1-2a_1)(a_2c_3-a_3c_2)+(b_3-2a_3)(a_1c_2-a_2c_1) \tag{2}$$

I don't know what else to do here, I've thought maybe about stating $1=2$ and that would mean $$(b_2-2a_2)=b_2\\
(b_1-2a_1)=b_1\\
(b_3-2a_3)=b_3$$

Therefore:

$$B=
        \left|\begin{bmatrix}
        a_3 & a_2 & a_1 \\
        b_3 & b_2 & b_1 \\
        c_3 & c_2 & c_1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right|=k
$$

Comment: \begin{bmatrix} instead of \begin{matrix}, do the same to \end.

Comment: On the last equality do you mean determinants or what?

Comment: Yes, (1)=(2). Thank you, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}$$
and so we have
$$\det(B)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}\det(A)\det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}.$$
Can you find the determinants of these two matrices?

Comment: Yes, I got 1 and -1 respectively. I don't see how's that different from what I found?

Comment: It's the same answer, but your reasoning is not correct (as (1) and (2) are not equal in general).

Comment: Oh! So how could I explain it without an example?